# ¿Cómo cambiar el idioma del calendario?

Tags: php

Supuestamente en la web, la siguiente línea de código `setlocale(LC_TIME,"es_ES");` convertía todo en español, pero no es así, no se que otro parámetro se debe agregar.

actualmente la siguiente línea `$calendar .= '<h2 class="monthYear">'.strftime($monthName).' '.$year.'</h2>';` me imprime `November 2020` lo que deseo es poder cambiar el idioma fácilmente así como `date_default_timezone_set` que me determina una zona horaria según los parámetros o datos que se le agreguen.

Dado a lo que deseo conseguir en el código, como puedo hacer que dicha función `setlocale(LC_TIME,"es_ES");` o que otro cambio debo agregar o corregir para poder cambiar el idioma globalmente.

Este es mi código

```
<?php
    
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Guayaquil');
    setlocale(LC_TIME,"es_ES");

    //Check date register
    function checkSlots(){
        $TotalBookings = 0;
        return $TotalBookings;
    }

    //Print calendar //$month = 11; //$year = 2020;
    function BuildCalendar($month, $year){

        //Lunes martes Miércoles Jueves Viernes Sábado Domingo // Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday
        // Create array containing abbreviations of days of week.
        $daysOfWeek = array('LUN.','MAR.','MIÉ.','JUE.','VIE.','SÁB.','DOM.');
        // What is the first day of the month in question?
        $firstDayOfMonth = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);
        // How many days does this month contain?
        $numberDays = date('t',$firstDayOfMonth);
        // Retrieve some information about the first day of the
        // month in question.
        $dateComponents = getdate($firstDayOfMonth);
        // What is the name of the month in question?
        $monthName = $dateComponents['month'];
        // What is the index value (0-6) of the first day of the
        // month in question.
        $dayOfWeek = $dateComponents['wday'];

        if($dayOfWeek==0){
            $dayOfWeek = 6;
        } else {
            $dayOfWeek = $dayOfWeek-1;
        }

        // Create the table tag opener and day headers
        $datetoday = date('Y-m-d');

        $calendar = "<table class='table-calendar'>";
        $calendar .="<center>";
        $calendar .= '<h2 class="monthYear">'.strftime($monthName).' '.$year.'</h2>';
        
        //btn btn-xs btn-primary
        //$calendar.= "<a class='changemonth' data-target='?month=".date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month-1, 1, $year))."&year=".date('Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month-1, 1, $year))."'>Mes anterior</a> ";
        //$calendar.= " <a class='changemonth' data-target='?month=".date('m')."&year=".date('Y')."'>Mes actual</a> ";
        //$calendar.= "<a class='changemonth' data-target='?month=".date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month+1, 1, $year))."&year=".date('Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month+1, 1, $year))."'>Mes siguiente</a><br>";
        
        $calendar .="</center>";
        $calendar .= "<tr>";

        // Create the calendar headers
        foreach($daysOfWeek as $day) {
            $calendar .= "<th  class='header_weekday'>$day</th>";
        }

        // Create the rest of the calendar
        // Initiate the day counter, starting with the 1st.
        $currentDay = 1;
        $calendar .= "</tr><tr>";

        // The variable $dayOfWeek is used to
        // ensure that the calendar
        // display consists of exactly 7 columns.
        if ($dayOfWeek > 0) {
            for($k=0;$k<$dayOfWeek;$k++){
                $calendar .= "<td  class='empty'></td>";
            }
        }

        $month = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

        while ($currentDay <= $numberDays) {
            // Seventh column (Saturday) reached. Start a new row.
            if ($dayOfWeek == 7) {
                $dayOfWeek = 0;
                $calendar .= "</tr><tr>";
            }

            $currentDayRel = str_pad($currentDay, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $date = "$year-$month-$currentDayRel";
            $dayName = strtolower(date('l', strtotime($date)));
            //$eventNum = 0;
            $today = $date==date('Y-m-d')? "today" : "";

            if ($date<date('Y-m-d')) {
                $calendar.="<td class='$today'><h4>$currentDay</h4> <button class='btn-danger'>N/A</button>";
            } elseif($dayName=='monday' || $dayName=='tuesday' || $dayName=='wednesday' || $dayName=='thursday' || $dayName=='friday') {
                $TotalBookings = checkSlots();
                if($TotalBookings==4) {
                    $calendar.="<td class='$today'><h4>$currentDay</h4> <a href='#' class='btn-danger'>Reservado</a>";
                } else {
                    $availableslots = 4 - $TotalBookings;
                    $calendar.="<td class='$today'><h4>$currentDay</h4> <a id='dateCalendar' class='dateCalendar' data-target='".$date."'>Disponible</a> <small><i>$availableslots Turnos</i></small>";
                }

            }elseif($dayName=='saturday' || $dayName=='sunday') {

                $TotalBookings = checkSlots();
                if($TotalBookings==4) {
                    $calendar.="<td class='$today'><h4>$currentDay</h4> <a href='#' class='btn-danger'>Reservado</a>";
                } else {
                    $availableslots = 4 - $TotalBookings;
                    $calendar.="<td class='$today'><h4>$currentDay</h4> <a id='dateCalendar' class='dateCalendar' data-target='".$date."'>Disponible</a> <small><i>$availableslots Turnos</i></small>";
                }
            }

            $calendar .="</td>";

            // Increment counters
            $currentDay++;
            $dayOfWeek++;
        }

        if($daysOfWeek<7){
            $remainingDays = 7 - $dayOfWeek;
            for($i=0;$i<$remainingDays;$i++){
                $calendar .= "<td class='empty'></td>";
            }
        }

        $calendar .= "</tr>";
        $calendar .= "</table>";

        return $calendar;

    }

    #Print rows date //$_GET
    $dateComponents = getdate();
    if(isset($_GET['month']) && isset($_GET['year'])){
        $month = $_GET['month'];
        $year = $_GET['year'];
    }else{
        $month = $dateComponents['mon'];
        $year = $dateComponents['year'];
    }

    echo BuildCalendar($month, $year);
?>
<style type="text/css">
    .today {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues, no es mucho lo que hay que cambiar en realidad.
Lancé tu código, y edite un par de cosas:

- Por algún motivo, setlocale() no funciona bien con "es_ES", asi que solo usa "es"

```
setlocale(LC_TIME,"es");
```

- El otro problema, es que no estás aplicando `strftime()` correctamente.
Para que funcione debidamente, debe tener el cambio de formato respectivo, 
en este caso, quieres el mes con respecto a `setlocale()` ("%B")
Pero además de eso, le estás pasando un `string` el cual es el mes, para que ese mes se respete, debes parsearlo a `time`. Al final quedaría algo como esto:

```
$calendar .= '<h2 class="monthYear">'.strtoupper(strftime("%B", strtotime($monthName))).' '.$year.'</h2>';
```

Finalmente, el resultado que estoy obteniendo con esto es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

He intentado reducir tu ejemplo a la mínima expresión, ya que hay muchas cosas que no nos interesan:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME,"es_ES");
$dateComponents = getdate();
$month = $dateComponents['mon'];
$year = $dateComponents['year'];

$firstDayOfMonth = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);

$monthName = $dateComponents['month'];


echo strftime($monthName);
```

El problema aquí es que `strftime` espera una cadena con marcas y un timestamp.
Y tu solo le estás pasando "November" que no significa nada para la función.

Un ejemplo que debería funcionarte es:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8');
echo strftime("%B", $firstDayOfMonth);
```